# How to run C++ process directly on database server to avoid transmitting data set?

Tags: c++, r, plsql, sas

Is it possible (or recommended) to compile & execute C++ code on a database server? Is there an application that allows a programmer to write C++ code from within PL/SQL?

I'm thinking of ways to more efficiently perform statistical analyses on large datasets residing on my company's server. Rather than transmitting the dataset to my local machine (which may take several hours) in order to run a regression in SAS or R, it seems far more efficent to perform the anaysis on the server itself. This has the added benefit of taking advantage of the server's extra RAM and memory compared with my lowly PC.

I'd like to code the matrix algebra required for more complex regressions (generalized linear models such as logistic regressions with random effects). I've read in a few forums that SQL isn't the ideal language for performing matrix algebra much less statistical analysis. Other languages like SAS can access data on a server, but the data must be downloaded to my machine and the analysis itself is conducted on my PC rather than the server itself. Hence my interest in running C++.

Comment: You _might_ want http://kx.com/

Comment: As opposed to C++ client side coding?

Comment: For linear algebra, regression, machine learning inside databases,
you may want to look at [madlib](http://madlib.net/)
or [scidb](http://scidb.org/).

Comment: Even basic postgresql has some stat functions (e.g. linear regression)

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, I'll look into these options. I don't know enough about data warehouse architecture, but would be neat if I could piggyback a big statistical analysis job onto the server, say during downtime at night. I mean, servers have gobs of RAM, right, that's wasted on doing routine data queries? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database server should be a database server.  It should not run application code.  Bite the bullet and either transfer the data down to your local machine, or buy an application server and properly connect it to the DB server using fast storage and a fast network path.

The extra work you'd do - not to mention the increase in errors - would not be worth the additional cost of either time or expense for the applications server in rewriting the code to perform regressions and other complex statistical processes.  There's a reason SAS can afford to charge hundreds or thousands per installation - because they've done all that work and tested it thoroughly.

Comment: Ok, thanks again Joe for answering my statistical programming/server questions. I guess other people have gone down this path before, trying to maximize performance from existing resources.

Comment: Congrats on the shiny new mod tools. You deserve it.